# Very slow SQL query when selecting XML column with connect by

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

background of the story is : I have an Oracle DB with a table storing data in XML column. I also have a view created to read data from the XML table in more readable sql way. The view has (important parts) : `guid, parent_guid, is_active, is_deleted, xmlcol`. Now I want to select a hierarchy and do SYS_XMLAGG using the view :

```
SELECT SYS_XMLAGG(v.xmlcol, XMLFormat('return'))
FROM xml_view v
WHERE is_active=true AND is_deleted=false
STARTS WITH v.guid=[given_guid_here]
AND v.is_active=true AND v.is_deleted=false
CONNECT BY v.parent_guid=PRIOR v.guid AND v.is_active=true AND v.is_deleted=false
```

But the query is sooo slow - it takes about 120 seconds to get 172 records. Similar query using 
XMLTABLE worked nearly instantly compared to that.
Columns on the view are indexed (guid, parent guid, active, deleted). When I do `SELECT xmlcol (...)` it also is very slow, but when i do `SELECT guid (...)` (using the above query, only changing what I select) it's normally quick again. What's the problem between xmlcol and selecting a hierarchy using CONNECT BY PRIOR?

Do you have any alternatives for that query? I need to use the view, not the XMLTABLE.

Comment: Please run an explain plan and show results.

Comment: Explain plan : [link](http://pastebin.com/Ryb3HKGb)